# Build specific configuration

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Is there any Visual Studio extension available, that allows you to right-click a solution/project in the solution explorer and build as a specific configuration?
I find Visual Studio extremely slow at changing configuration, which is why I usually rely on running MSBuild directly.
A context menu below the Build action with all the configurations available would be quite nice.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the main menu, select `Build->Batch Build...` and select the configuration/platform combination(s) you want to build. It's not ideal when you have a lot of projects though.